# I installed Matomo but I see only realt time visitor. Matomo doesn't record any logs

Tags: ftp, matomo, piwiktracker

I installed Matomo from https://builds.piwik.org/ but I see only real time visitor. Matomo doesn't record any logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you only see the visitors in the real-time log, but no reports generated, make sure either browser archiving is enabled or you are running archiving via a cronjob:

https://matomo.org/docs/setup-auto-archiving/

Comment: Ok. I created a cronjob. Thank you!